# Android's CoordinatorLayout in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Is there any way I can implement a layout with a collapsing header in Xamarin.Forms? I know this can be achieved in Android (CoordinatorLayout) and thus Xamarin.Droid as well but I'm looking for a way to be able to do the same thing for iOS.

If there is no support already in place in Xamarin.Forms to be able to do this, is there a better way to implement it without reading the position of the scroll and changing the height of the header every time a scroll event occurs?

For reference, this is what I'm looking to be able to do in Xamarin.iOS:
[image: Coordinator Layout]

Comment: Do you want to achieve that in Xamarin.forms? CoordinatorLayout is not supported in Xamarin.forms, it uses the RelativeLayout for Android in Xamarin.forms.

Comment: @Kevin I'm aware CoordinatorLayout isn't supported in Forms but I was wondering if there was something to mimic it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [ScrollView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scroll-view/) with its [Scrolled](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView.Scrolled/) event to achieve your animation.

Or you can use a third-party NuGet to achieve that, like this one: [XFParallax](https://github.com/DevsDNA/XFParallax).